# Environmental Variables in .classpath xml

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, tomcat

I've this line in .classpath file in Eclipse (Dynamic Web Project). I got this by adding an external jar from "build path" option.

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/lib/some.jar" sourcepath="/Scrubber"/>
```

But I already have CATALINA_HOME set in my system.
I want to replace `path="D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/lib/some.jar"` to `path="[CATALINA_HOME]/lib/some.jar"`

What is the correct syntax for it. I tried

```
path="${CATALINA_HOME}/lib/some.jar"

path="${env:CATALINA_HOME}/lib/some.jar"

path="${env.CATALINA_HOME}/lib/some.jar"

path="${catalina.home}/lib/some.jar"

path="${catalina.base}/lib/some.jar"
```

None of them worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The class path entry will not resolve environment variables so this won't work.

The closest you can get is to use the Eclipse Preferences 'Java > Build Path > Classpath Variables' to define a similar CATALINA_HOME variable inside Eclipse.

Once you have the Eclipe Classpath Variable defines you can use the 'Add Variable...' button on the 'Java Build Path' property page in the 'Libraries' section.

This will give you a class path entry looking like:

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="CATALINA_HOME/lib/some.jar"/>
```

note that the 'kind' is 'var' rather than 'lib'.

Comment: While defining the CATALINA_HOME variable from Eclipse Preferences 'Java > Build Path > Classpath Variables' . I've to mention the absolute path against the variable. But this is what I dont want because in different system the server installation folder may be different and it doesn't have the option for configuring eclipse there, I just have to deploy the WAR.
Is there any way to create this CATALINA_HOME and link with %CATALINA_HOME%, so I don't have to hard code the absolute path directly ?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to set a global variable on Eclipse level or on project level.
Learn how to do it in Eclipse docs. 
Basically you need to go to Run -> Run Configurations... and Select tab "Environment".The relevant article is [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcpathvars.htm).

To use your variable: (based on a system environment variable) select Add variable string, in .classpath type: `${env_var:your-environment-variable-name}/path-to-jar`. For example, if your system environment variable is `MYVAR` and the JAR file is under subdir/myfile.jar, you should type `${env_var:MYVAR}/subdir/myfile.jar`.

[image]

Comment: I've created  SERVER_HOME which links to CATALINA_HOME from system.
Now, when I wrote <classpathentry kind="lib" path="${env_var:SERVER_HOME}/lib/some.jar" sourcepath="/Scrubber"/>

And then I went to build path and seeing an error icon beside some.jar because it reading as \WEBPROJECT\SERVER_HOME}\lib\some.jar

Comment: you must be careful with CATALINA_HOME in Eclipse as Eclipse has a built in Tomcat server. Link you variable to an absolute path first to see that it works.

Comment: Yeah with absolute path its working properly. I just have to replace that absolute path and change it to a path with environmental variable. But its is not working :(

Comment: you can try and redefine CATALINA_HOME at project level and then chain it while defining SERVER_HOME